# How to convert POJO to map with types retained?

Tags: java, pojo

I need to convert a POJO to a map. I tried using Object mapper but types like timestamp are coming either as String or as Long in the final map. Is there some tool that would do a simple conversion that would result in a map having exactly the same objects as in the POJO ? (I know I can use reflection but want to see if there is an easier way.)

Comment: Can you post an example what you exactly mean and what it does look like currently? You can add every thing to a map if the type is matching or you can `extend` your pojo by MAP is you want it to be a MAP-class

Comment: Please show your code (where you tried to use "Object mapper"). What do you mean with "Object mapper" - are you using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)'s `ObjectMapper` to convert a POJO to JSON? Or do you want to convert it to a `java.util.Map`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done directly with [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) [describe](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#describe-java.lang.Object-) or [BeanMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanMap.html):

```
Map<Object, Object> map = BeanUtils.describe(object); 

Map<Object, Object> map = new BeanMap(object);
```

Comment: We have adopted this solution. Thanks.

Comment: The return type for describe() is more accurately  Map<String, String>